# Variables in Chronicle

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Why does every single condition in the event section have a variable in front of a the UDM event or entity fields? For example, in the following why do we need to prefix `$selection` before `metadata.product_event_type`:

```
events:
  $selection.metadata.product_event_type = "1"
```

In the following rule:

```
o   rule whoami_execution {
o   meta:
o      author = "Florian Roth"
o      description = "Detects the execution of whoami, which is often used by attackers after exploitation / privilege escalation but rarely used by administrators  License: https://github.com/Neo23x0/sigma/blob/master/LICENSE.Detection.Rules.md."
o      reference = "https://tdm.socprime.com/tdm/info/uA0vQNIJsZGW"
o      version = "0.01"
o      created = "2018/05/22"
o      product = "windows"
o      service = "sysmon"
o      mitre = "discovery, t1033"
o   events:
o      $selection.metadata.product_event_type = "1"  
o      $selection.target.process.command_line = "whoami"
o   
o   condition:
o      $selection
}
```

Is `$selection` a variable for `metadata.product_event_type` or `target.process.command_line`. And if both, how can a variable hold two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [YARA-L 2.0](https://cloud.google.com/chronicle/docs/detection/yara-l-2-0-overview#multiple_event_rule), all variables are represented as **$variable_name.** Variables can be defined within rules. They can be very important when comparing multiple events as well as temporarily storing specific values from events. The variables can then be used in performing actions such as counting the number of times an event occurs.

There are three different types of variables.

1. Event
2. Placeholder
3. Match.

Every single condition in the event section will have a variable in front of the UDM event or entity fields associated with it. The name of the variable can be arbitrary. This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/chronicle/docs/detection/yara-l-2-0-syntax#variables) will tell you that generally **$u** would indicate UDM events and **$e** would indicate UDM entity events and in some examples, you may see a variable like **$event** or **$selection.**

**EDIT**

In multi-event rules, the event variable will not hold any values. Here in the given rules,

```
$selection.metadata.product_event_type = "1"
$selection.target.process.command_line = "whoami"
```

The details of `product_event _type` and `target.process.command_line` is grouped under a single var called **$selection** which will not hold any value. It's just for naming or grouping the set of events.
**Placeholder variables** can be used to associate events with one another which will hold the values.

```
$selection.target.user.userid = $targetUser
```

In the above example, the `$targetUser` serves as a place where the `target.user.userid` value will reside. It can then be used to match other events with that same value. These placeholders can also be used in the outcome section.

**Match Variable:**

One or more variables can be used to group results. These variables must first be defined in the events section as a placeholder.

```
$targetUser over 5m
```

The match variables are similar to the placeholder variables in the sense that they have been described in the event section but when used in the match section, you are going to apply that variable against a time window. In this case, you will be taking all of the events with the target user meeting the event criteria and grouping by that value over a 5-minute window.

Comment: i have updated my question with an example. Can you help me deconstruct the same. I have looked at the docs, but I am still a bit confused about this.

Comment: @Nosail, I have made some changes in my answer. Can you please have a look and let me know if you have any further queries. I am happy to assist you.

Comment: Thank you, @Srividya. That was very helpful!